# .Split separating every single character

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

So I'm using a C# code to separate lines of strings and then further separate them using a comma.
I'm using this two to separate:

```
dataString = hs_get.text.Split('\n');
stringPairs = new string[dataString.Length][];
for (int o = 0; o < dataString.Length - 1; o++)
{
    Debug.Log (o);
    stringPairs[o] = dataString[o].Split(',');
    //Debug.Log (dataString[o][0] + " --- " + dataString[o][2]);
}
```

This is the PHP code that feeds this string:

php

```
// Send variables for the MySQL database class.
   $database = mysql_connect('X', 'X', 'X') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db('openfire_scores') or die('Could not select database');

   $query = "SELECT * FROM `scores` ORDER by `score` DESC LIMIT 5";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

   $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

   for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
   {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // Automatically advances one row after fetching
        echo $row['id'] . "," . $row['name'] . "," . $row['score'] . "\n";
   }
   >
```

And this is the table thats being used:

```
 id  | name     | score |

1    | Player 1 | 5     |

2    | Player 2 | 5     |

3    | Player 3 | 7     |
```

But instead of separating the words between the comma's, it separates every single character INCLUDING the comma and puts that into the array.
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I should mention I built off of this post: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-read-data-from-a-text-file-putting-a-lar.html

**Edit 2**

So today I had a breakthrough. This is the code I use now. I am still not sure why the previous code didn't work, but this one does.

```
dataString = hs_get.text.Split('\n');
            stringPairs = new string[dataString.Length][];
            for (int o = 0; o < dataString.Length; o++)
            {
                string[] trial = dataString[o].Split(',');
                stringPairs[o] = trial;


            }
```

Thanks for the all the help guys!

Comment: What language is this ?

Comment: Oh sorry for lacking. It's C#.

Comment: Code looks fine - please show data you are using. Side note consider never using `o` as variable name (especially with indexing) since it looks like `0`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - good point. That's why I always use `l` instead!

Comment: @JonB - :) indeed some smart*** have fonts that distinguish between `O` and `0`, so agree `l` have better chance to wreck havoc.

Comment: code works - unless there is something funny about your data. I see one error you are not iterating over the entire dataString array. You should change your loop to be for (int o = 0; o < dataString.Length; o++)

Comment: @user3171065 - in your edit you posted pipe (|) delimited data, not comma. Am I missing something?

Comment: @chaddienhart - looks like an asnwer to me

Comment: @JonB In the table? Thats just for show. Its the way in the PHP section that determines the comma.

Comment: @user3171065 - OK, I think what people are asking for is a sample of the actual data.

Comment: @JonB Im not entirely sure which data you mean? I assumed data meant the table of the SQL database.

Comment: @JdR - no, the content of the database. The string you are splitting (`dataString`).

Comment: @JonB That is that table. That's all thats in the database.
So far with Debug.Log it has returned the following:
1,Player 1,5 /
2,Player 2,5 / etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to work but skips the last row, you should drop the -1 unless you intend to skip the last row. 
Here is an example:

```
    string text = "1,Player 1,5\n2,Player 2,5\n3,Player 3,7";
    string [] dataString = text.Split('\n');
    string [][] stringPairs = new string[dataString.Length][];
    for (int o = 0; o < dataString.Length; o++)
    {
        //Debug.Log(o);
        stringPairs[o] = dataString[o].Split(',');
        //Debug.Log (dataString[o][0] + " --- " + dataString[o][2]);
    }
```

the array looks as follows:

```
stringPair[0]
  [0]1
  [1]Player 1
  [2]5
stringPair[1]
  [0]2
  [1]Player 2
  [2]5
stringPair[2]
  [0]3
  [1]Player 3
  [2]7
```

Comment: So I removed that -1, and yet with this code and logging that, I get the result that stringPair[x][1] is ",". I even used your example string text instead of the PHP retrieved text

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? The code returns the array as I have printed it on my PC. I'm using .NET 4.0

Comment: I am currently coding in Unity 4, which a quick google search suggests has the equivalent of .Net 3.5

Comment: any luck? what does the contents of dataString[o] look like each time through the loop?

Comment: I had a breakthrough just now. For some reason the code (as posted above in original question) works now. I have no idea why your, or any of the other code, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mirror the way the PHP code does it.

You could write something like this:

```
private string[][] Work(string hs_get_text) {
  var lines = hs_get_text.Split('\n');
  int linesLength = lines.Length;
  var pairs = new List<string[]>(linesLength);
  foreach (var line in lines) {
    pairs.Add(line.Split(','));
  }
  return pairs.ToArray();
}
```

The [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class is very powerful. If you are in .Net, you should use it to save some headaches.

Comment: Thanks! Ill look into this. I havent encountered that "Work" thing before; what does it do?

Comment: **Work** is just the name of the function I used to test the code. I passed in the string `hs_get_text` and returned the **string[][]** array.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, but this is working fine for me, perhaps a better alternative. I tried recreating the sample from the unity answer.

```
const string hs_get_text = "apple,ball\ncar,dog\negg,fish\ngoat,hat";
var dataString = hs_get_text.Split('\n');
var list = new List<string[]>(dataString.Length - 1);
foreach (string s in dataString)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(s);
    list.Add(s.Split(','));
}
```

And if you needed the list of string to be an array, you can just call `.ToArray()` on the list.